# how to compare integers when a condition is met

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that reads a text file that contains football teams with the number of goals they scored  I want to be able to scan the text file for a certain team then work out such things as goals scored gaols against and so on.

```
public void totalGames()
    { 


        File inputfile = new File ("validtest.txt.txt");
        try{

            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
            //Map<String[], int[]> teams = new Map<>();
            HashMap<String,String> teamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(filescan.hasNext()){
            //  StrArray = aLine.split(separator);


                String[] teamKey = filescan.nextLine().split(" : ");


                teamMap.put(teamKey[0], teamKey[1]);





                }
            filescan.close();
            System.out.println(teamMap);

                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){


                }
                        I have managed to add only the teams to the map but it is making the teams equals to each other where as the team needs to be associated with the goals scored in that game.

Fulham : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Wigan Athletic : Leeds United : 2 : 2
Arsenal : Liverpool : 2 : 2
```

Comment: Fulham are rubbish this season, again.  They would never score against Liverpool, even at home.

Comment: have a look at the concept of a ```Map```

Comment: A double `Map` (i.e. Key -> Value and Value -> Key) with an embellishment to prevent the key equalling the value (just for an extra safety check) would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

**DataModel is the keyword !**

I would suggest to create a `DataModel`.

- Found new line
- parse to model
- add model to arraylist
- retrieve user's input
- check if there is a model which has exact same value as user's input
- if yes retrieve other informations from your model

If the user enters the team's name, try to look for a model which has the exact same team in it via `contains()` and `indexOf()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

- Create a new class with following details:

  - teamName
  - oppnonent
  - goals
  - otherGoals
  - define equals with opponent name field as key attribute to match
- Read from file and store the data in a map with key as teamName, and value as list of objects with above details.
- Read input team name from user and then goto map and fetch team details from list and show it to the user.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by define equals with opponent name field as key attribute to match?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to associate each team with the number of goals they scored. The [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) data structure is what you need.

In your case store all teams as keys in the map and accumulate the scored goals for each team. Give it a try and edit your question if you have any troubles.

**EDIT:**

```
// HashMap<Team, GoalsScored>
HashMap<String,Integer> teamMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String[] teamKey = filescan.nextLine().split(" : ");

String team1 = teamKey[0];
String team2 = teamKey[1];
Integer team1goals = Integer.valueOf(teamKey[2]);
Integer team2goals = Integer.valueOf(teamKey[3]);

// if team1 is not in the map initialise with 0 goals
if (!teamMap.containsKey(team1)) {
    teamMap.put(team1, 0);
// if team2 is not in the map initialise with 0 goals
if (!teamMap.containsKey(team2)) {
    teamMap.put(team2, 0);

// accumulate team1 goals
teamMap.put(team1, teamMap.get(team1) + team1goals);
// accumulate team2 goals
teamMap.put(team2, teamMap.get(team2) + team2goals);
```

Comment: how do you associate the goals with the team? im not sure on how you split the line in order to put the ints with the correct strings.

Comment: I've tried this method but it fails when assigning teamkey[3] to team2goals ?

Comment: What is the problem? Maybe you cannot parse " 2 " to string? Find a way to remove those whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a new `Game` or `Match` class, then loop throught your file and store the matches details in a `list<Match>`:

```
public Class Match{
 String team;
 int score:
 String opponent;
 int opponentScore;
}
```

Then for each line store the match details in a `Match` instance then add it to a list of Match.

The your display would be like:

```
System.out.println(match.team+":"+match.opponent+" "+match.score+":"+match.opponentScore);
```

where `match` represents every element of your match list.

I think that should do it.